# Parsing C struct using ANTLR

Tags: parsing, struct, antlr, lexer

Is parsing C struct using ANTLR possible? if so, is there any existing tool/grammar file?
the code will be like this:

```
typedef struct C {
    int i;
    float f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is parsing C struct using ANTLR possible?

Yes.

> if so, is there any existing tool/grammar file?

There are C grammars for both ANTLR3 and ANTLR4:

- v3 grammars: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html
- v4 grammars: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4